# How to get the real date and time of the country using Javascript even if the device time is wrong?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, date-format

Is there a way to get the actual date and time of the country in Javascript even if the device time is inaccurate?

Say:

1. I am in Austin Texas, US (GMT-6) and it is Jan 27, 2021, 9:20pm
2. I change the device date and time Feb 1, 2021, 6:03pm
3. Using Javascript, how do I get the actual date and time in Mumbai India?

Comment: `new Date()` in JavaScript will always read the time from the user's device. To handle this, you need to get the date-time from the server.

Comment: On the client side, you can't. Unless you make a request to an external service that provides you with accurate time information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve actual date/time from your device alone unless its system time is accurate.

Using Javascript (and a bit of help from Fetch API), you can always get current time from the third-party services like this.

[World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org/)

```js
fetch('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Belgrade')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Awesome. This is really helpful.